# Loading YAML in R without converting 'Yes' to True and 'No' to False

Tags: r, yaml

How can I read the following string where 'Yes' are not converted to true

```
string <- "
a: 
 cc : dd
 dd : ee
b: 
 ee : Yes
 ff : 1
"
```

Now I get

```
yaml.load(string)

#$a
#$a$cc
#[1] "dd"
#$a$dd
#[1] "ee"
#
#$b
#$b$ee
#[1] TRUE
#$b$ff
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `identity` function as a `hanlder`:

```
yaml.load(string, handlers = list("bool#yes" = identity))
```

which gives you:

```
$a
NULL

$cc
[1] "dd"

$dd
[1] "ee"

$b
NULL

$ee
[1] "Yes"

$ff
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a documentation where I can read a bit more about handlers?

Comment: @imsc, the only place I know is in `?yaml.load`